# Pytest - Using Fxture and decorator toghether giving and issue

Tags: python, pytest

Below is the code

```
import pytest

# Fixture definition
@pytest.fixture
def sample_data():
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return data

# Decorator definition
def custom_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Decorator: Before test function")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Decorator: After test function")
        return result
    return wrapper

# Test function using both fixture and decorator
@custom_decorator
def test_sum_of_data(sample_data):
    total = sum(sample_data)
    assert total == 15

# Run the tests
if __name__ == "main":
    pytest.main()
```

Here is ther error

```
args = (), kwargs = {}

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Decorator: Before test function")
>       result = func(*args, **kwargs)
E       TypeError: test_sum_of_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sample_data'

230823_pytest_deco.py:13: TypeError
```

I am passing 'sample_data' as argument still getting an error.
Help me resolve the issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the decorator as follows (add functools.wraps) :

```
def custom_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Decorator: Before test function")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Decorator: After test function")
        return result
    return wrapper
```

`functools.wraps`  takes a function used in a decorator and adds the functionality of copying over the function name, docstring, arguments list, etc.  this way you don't loose anything related to the function.

Comment: Thanks ozs it worked.
Also can you explain explanation behind adding that line ?